# Compute the value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100}\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Earlier today I was given the following problem by a friend:

> Define the sets $A_i$ as $A_1=\{1,2,3\},A_2=\{2,3,4\},\dots,A_k=\{k,k+1,k+2\}$. Given that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^kA_n=A_1\cup A_2\cup\dots\cup A_k$, compute the value of  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100}\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i\right|$.
>
> (A) $5044$; (B) $5050$; (C) $5350$; (D) $5356$; (E) not listed

I determined the solution by observing $\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k A_i\right|=2+k$ and thus computing the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{100}(2+k)=200+50(101)=5250$. Stating the answer then must be (E), my friend told me I was incorrect and that the correct solution gave (C), $5350$. He provided the following excerpt from the answer key as proof:

[image]

After glancing at the above it appears to me this solution is incorrect; the cardinality where $k=100$ should in fact be $102$
, giving an identical sum to the one I found above -- $3+4+\cdots+102=5250$.

Unfortunately my friend is not convinced his answer key could contain an error. Can anyone tell which one of us is correct? Apologies in advance if I made any trivial mistakes in typing this. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The key gives a perfectly correct method, but as you say, the value of the term corresponding to $k=100$ is given incorrectly as $103$ instead of $102$. This even contradicts the key’s correct implication (from the description of $\bigcup_{n=1}^kA_n$ as $\{1,2,3,\ldots,k,k+1,k+2\}$) that it should be $100+2$.

Comment: Thanks, I was doubting myself earlier. Kudos. Unfortunately I have to wait 4 more minutes before being able to mark this as my accepted answer.

Comment: @oldrinb: You’re welcome. (I know that doubting feeling myself.)